# Java Getter and Setters for simple properties best practice

Tags: java, properties

I know this is a common question and I've read several answers but they're all very subjective and I'm trying to get an answer on best common practice (i.e what to use a majority of the time).

My background is in C# .net and I'm re-writing an application in Java (ver. 21). With C# a public property with a getter and setter is functionally the same thing as a private field with a public getter and setter (C# example below). The get and set are implicitly used when referencing the property. So in practice 99% of the time I use a public property with getter and setter because it gives me the added benefit of encapsulation and doesn't add any verbosity to the code.

Now with Java I'm struggling when to use getters and setters. If I where to code like I do with C#, most of my java object properties would be private fields with public getter and setter methods. That makes the code really verbose (example1 below) and I'm not sure if it's necessary/common for simple objects like json responses (mapped by jackson) or entities.

So with that all being said, **in practice what is the most standard way of handling simple properties that just get and set a field in Java (without data manipulation)**. Like if I where to see an enterprise application what would be the most standard way of handling example1 and example2 below. Based on my research thus far I'm leaning towards example1 (keeps encapsulation), but I don't want to use getters and setters everywhere if it's actually more common practice to just use public fields with simple properties. Let me know your thoughts.

C# get/set:

```
namespace SpeedRunAppImport.Model.Entity
{
    public class GameEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        // Same thing as above
        private string _Name;
        public string Name
        { 
            get
            {
                return _Name;
            }
            set
            {
                _Name = value;
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Game Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_game")
public class Game {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)    
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String code;
    private String abbreviation;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCode() {
         return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
         this.code = code;
    }

    public String getAbbreviation() {
         return abbreviation;
    }

    public void setAbbreviation(String abbreviation) {
         this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
    }
}
```

GameResponse (JSON response mapped by Jackson):

```
public class GameResponse
{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String abbreviation;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
         return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
         this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAbbreviation() {
         return abbreviation;
    }

    public void setAbbreviation(String abbreviation) {
         this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
    }
}
```

Example1 (using getters/setters):

```
public void SaveGames(List<GameResponse> games)
{
    _logger.info("Started SaveGames: {@count}", games.size());
    
    var existingGamesVWs = _gameRepo.GetGamesByCode(games.stream().map(x -> x.getId()).toList());            

    var gameEntities = games.stream().map(i -> { var game = new Game();
                              var existingGame = existingGamesVWs.stream().filter(x -> x.code == i.getId()).findFirst().orElse(null);
                              game.setId(existingGame != null ? existingGame.getId() : null);
                              game.setName(i.getName());
                              game.setCode(i.getId());
                              game.setAbbr(i.getAbbreviation());

                              return game;
                            }).toArray(Game[]::new);


    _logger.info(Integer.toString(existingGamesVWs.size()));
}
```

Example2 using fields (assume public fields on objects above):

```
public void SaveGames(List<GameResponse> games)
{
    _logger.info("Started SaveGames: {@count}", games.size());
    
    var existingGamesVWs = _gameRepo.GetGamesByCode(games.stream().map(x -> x.id).toList());             

    var gameEntities = games.stream().map(i -> { var game = new Game();
                              var existingGame = existingGamesVWs.stream().filter(x -> x.code == i.id).findFirst().orElse(null);
                              game.id = existingGame != null ? existingGame.id : null;
                              game.name = i.name;
                              game.code = i.id;
                              game.abbr = i.abbreviation;

                              return game;
                            }).toArray(Game[]::new);
}
```

Comment: I don’t quite grok why this much code is required as an example. In the end this is opinion. Getters and setters are the norm for if you’re not using records.

Comment: Well people always want to see the objects involved, code is pretty readable imo. If i just put the last 2 examples ppl would be asking for the objects lol. Also wanted to illustrate that using getter/setter, they're going to be like everywhere, literally anywhere I get or set.

Comment: … you’re asking about getters/setters vs public members when there’s no data manipulation required ‍♂️ YMMV but seems like very little is required to demonstrate what you’re asking (if anything). I’d also argue this has been discussed to death in the world already.

Comment: True, and i've read the articles and there's really a lot conjecture. Use records, don't use records due to immutability. Use lombok, wait don't use lombok because it was once tied to specific IDEs (i'm using Visual Studio Code) and can cause additional confusion. If it's simple properties on immutable objects just use fields, wait don't use fields it looses encapsulation. I wanted a simple concise "this is what most people are doing" answer, a lot of code practices can be argued to death, I'm looking for what standard boiler plate is in 2024 for this problem.

Comment: As you’ve discovered it’s down to opinion and open to debate. Do what works for your particular situation and ecosystem.

Comment: Right the question is what is most often used. Not an opinion based thing, more what is the most common approach in practice. If that's using getters and setters for everything then fine, I just wanted to know whats most common as I don't have access to enterprise java code to see.

Comment: YMMV but there’s a ton of open-source Java code available. I suppose you could use a simple parser to quantify what the “most common” pattern is if it’s that important.

Comment: Yes perusing some examples on github I see a lot of usage of getters/setters, so leaning in that direction. Thanks for feedback.

Comment: I don’t know how you imagine that asking the same question again would give you less subjective answers. You should at least link to some of the answers you have read so we know more precisely what it is that you don’t want.

Comment: Well when the question is phrased "what is most standard/common" you would think ppl would give you that answer. And as you see below that answer has been given. The question is entirely relevant, I'm not looking for an internet debate, I'm looking for a real world answer, thanks.

Comment: “That makes the code really verbose…” —That’s what javadoc is for.  A fundamental concept in object-oriented development is that when you want a summary of the capabilities of a class, you are supposed to look at the documentation—the contract—not the internal implementation.  C#’s generated documentation is awkward and clumsy (or was last time I looked), but javadoc is streamlined and organized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common approach or convention with Java is to use Getters and Setters to respect the encapsulation principle and make classes easier to mock/test, as in any other language. Some languages for a long time made this easier and less verbose, C# and Kotlin being good examples of that.

However, Java generally favors stability over syntactic sugar, not to mention that not too many years ago the release cycle used to be a lot longer, and these syntax improvements would take more time to be available.

A couple of ways to achieve it:

###### 1. Explicitly declare getters and setters ([JavaBeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) style)

```java
public class Example {
   private final String value;

   public Example(String value) {
       this.value = value;
   }

   public String getValue() {
       return this.value;
   }

   public void setValue(String value) {
       this.value = value;
   }
}
```

###### 2. Use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter)'s annotation processing, which generates the boilerplate at compile time, and can be used at the class level or the property level.

```java
@Getter
@Setter 
// or @Data, which adds more functionality (e.g. equals, hashCode, toString)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Example {
   private final String value;
}
```

###### 3. Use [Records](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395) in Java 16+, the best equivalent to a data class in other languages.

```
record Example(String value) {}
```

At the end of the day, the option depends on preference, but the principle of encapsulation and the testability quality attribute should ideally be respected.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the clear an concise answer. I've looked into records but because of their immutability I don't think it's super viable to use a majority of the time. Like you said for JSON responses (probably will use) or maybe DB Entities I could use them. But often times I'll pull an entity from the DB, update a property on it and send it back down to DB for save, so immutability there would be an issue. So sounds like its' option 1 or 2, lombok turned me off initially because its an IDE plugin and was hoping to keep my code agnostic. Looks like maybe option 1 is best bet, thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome. It's a valid point on records, although even in that case a common practice to keep objects immutable and thread-safe is to just create another record based on the original, with the necessary modifications, favoring safety over performance. Again, Kotlin's data classes make this easier like `example.copy(value = "other")`. Java does not offer anything like that (not natively anyway).

Comment: Yea good point, I can see that being pretty common practice with entities. Just was a bit of a design shock coming from c# where you use a property a public property and don't think much more about it. Probably one of the larger design differences to get used to everything else is nearly 1:1 (even with stream instead of linq, etc). So for now I'll just have to get used to the getters/setters :). Thanks again.